# Firestore security rules | enforcing field VALUES

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It is possible to [enforce field types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#enforcing_field_types) with firestore security rules **but is it possible to enforce field VALUE?**

Lets say when a message is seen by the user.. The message `seen` field gets updated to `true`. And because this can never go back to false. How do I write a rule to only update `seen` field if it is to be updated to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rules should:

- allow creating a message document with seen value as `false`
- update seen to `true` only that too it is currently `false`

```
 match /messages/{messageId} {
   allow create: if request.resource.data.seen == false;
   allow update: if resource.data.seen == false && request.resource.data.seen == true;
 }
```

Do update the rules as per other requirements e.g. user must be authenticated and so on.

`resource.data` contains data of document being updated and `request.resource.data` contains data to be added/updated in the document. More details about this can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)